# Why should we use sp for font sizes in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of px, dp, dip and sp in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

I am new to Android and I was trying out [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

In that tutorial, they used the unit "sp" for textSize attribute and "dp" for other attributes.

Please tell me how sp differs from dp?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The `dp` has constant ratio transition to `px`: `dp = px * ratio`. Where `ratio` will never change on any particular device.

While `sp` (s for scaled) has scalable ratio: `sp = px * ratio * scale`. Where `ratio` never changes, but `scale` is user configurable. This `scale` can be used by people who need larger font sizes, for example, to use device more comfortably.

Comment: This feels wrong, why are our layouts based on `dp` but all text rendered inside that layout scaled to user's `sp` settings? If the text becomes larger, shouldn't the containing view also grows to accommodate them?

Comment: So, to simplify: `sp = dp * scale`

Comment: @chakrit You can use `sp` to build your layouts too.

Comment: @chakrit Not necessarily. If your views grow larger, the layout of your application will be different, which raises difficult questions. Should the views overlap? Should one displace another? Etc.

Comment: what can be value for `scale` ?

Comment: @chakrit Even if layouts are using dp, they should still be able to tolerate text becoming larger to some degree, otherwise this is poor design. Say, if a text label is constrained in width, it can still grow in height. If it's constrained in both, then you may have problems when the text becomes larger, for example, when translating into another language.

Answer (score 8):

Sp is scaled independently with respect to the normal font size of the device. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> Similarly, you should prefer the sp (scale-independent pixel) to define text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and the system scales the size the same as it does for dp.