# Determining user font size selection

Tags: android, fonts, font-size

I have an Android app that needs some adjustment if the user sets their font size to extra large (via Settings -> Display -> Font size in 4.0 and higher).

Is there a simple way for me to tell what the user's font size preference is

**Updated:**
in my layout.xml I have lines similar to  to setup a button

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:typeface="sans"
```

Notice that I'm not setting the font size directly.  This layout works and looks good in all cases, except for the **Extra Large** setting. In that case, due to space limitations, it causes the button's text to wrap to 2 lines.

My goal is to make a slight wording change in the case of **Extra Large** so that it doesn't wrap

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a [`FONT_SCALE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#FONT_SCALE) parameter you should be able to query the system for. I haven't used it myself, but I imagine retrieving its value would look somewhat like this:

```
float fontScale = Settings.System.getFloat(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.FONT_SCALE)
```

However, I'd also like to point out that usually you shouldn't be dealing with this value directly. In stead, use `sp` units for textual content so that you don't have to worry about adjusting to user-preferred font sizes yourself, but rather let the system handle that.

Also refer to: [Why should we use sp for font sizes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107920/why-should-we-use-sp-for-font-sizes-in-android)

Comment: Good point regarding sp, but not relevant in this case, see updated information in question

Comment: fontScale return 1.3 for ExtraLarge.  Would be nice to find a constant for this, but I can use it for now.

Comment: Strange your code throws for me a `SettingNotFoundException: font_scale`, but I'm sure that your and my code is correct (Android 4.2.2)

Comment: @rekire: Just read your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544931/read-font-size-from-settings), but I'm not sure what's going on. Perhaps the font scale value doesn't get set until you actually change it from its default? Might be worth a try. It's a bit far fetched, but the best I can think of right now.

Comment: I checked that too, the value does not matter the exception is always thrown.

Comment: I find this useful as a list component height scale (where wrapping could lead to inconsistent sizing) e.g. default height * (1 + (fontScale - 1) / 2)

Comment: Worth catching and handling `SettingNotFoundException` as we see this on one of our test (emulator) environments