# Universal Application with Dimensions files android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources, screen-resolution

I want to build universal application which will work on all devices pixel perfect.
I am confused about the dimensions folder? How do I managed the aspect ratio of the textsize in sp? and dp?

I have built a test project with different values folder for mdpi, hpdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. and manage the aspect ratio by following this answer: [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290575/what-should-be-the-text-size-ratio-in-android-for-multiple-density-device)

On NOTE 3 it get resources from xxhdpi and text size appears to large.

Can any one guide me how to make application UI pixel perfect?

What is the aspect ratio for dimens in values folder for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi?

Is it possible to make pixel perfect on every device? if yes then how? example please

What is the best solution to make different layout files for densities or different values(Dimens) files for densities?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from android 3.2 you should use resuorce qualifiers as specified [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

in your case you create

```
values-sw320dp #for phones
values-sw480dp #for tweener tablets
values-sw600dp #for 7" tablet
values-sw720dp #for 10" tablet
```

and add dimensions there

Comment: is it work on nexus 6, note3, and other phones? Same view on nexus 4, nexus 6, note3, Samsung galaxy s5?