# Scaled Pixels for FontSizes in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, fonts, label, xamarin.forms

I have problems with my font sizes on big screens.

By default, my label looks perfect on my small android phone.

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
       Text="Lobby" 
       FontSize="16" />
```

When I switch to my Amazon Fire Tablet, the label is very, very tiny. Almost everything is too tiny.

I have read, there is a unit "sp" for Android projects. Is there a built in way to do it in Xamarin.Forms? Are there libraries that could help me with that?

I already took a look at:
[Resolution-dependent font size in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527724/resolution-dependent-font-size-in-xamarin). Unfortunately I am using Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [NamedSize](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NamedSize/) enum for font sizes. 
The available ones are :

- Micro
- Small
- Medium
- Large

Eg:

```
<Label Text="Login" FontSize="Large"/>
<Label Text="Instructions" FontSize="Small"/>
```

Comment: what if i want to use custom font sizes not named size ? and which will scales same like named size

Comment: @MayurKerasiya - please post a new question if you are looking for some leads.

Answer (score 0):

Try use **Device.Idiom** if you are using PCL. Depend of type of device, you can add a different image size.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Device/

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom/

And this extended guide - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/

Comment: Link only answers are acceptable but try to add more content as the links might become obsolete.