# Adjust button text size with button height

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have a button that I set a particular height for and have the button text fill the entire button. I achieved this before by setting `textSize` to a specific dimension to fill the button.

But the problem is whenever the user changes the system font of his/her device, it affects the button text and the text overflows and gets cut in the button. How can I make the button text size match the height of the button?

Edit

The button's height is set to `match_parent` for it's parent widget

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/text_toolbar"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/k_i_n_e_c_t"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Set your button height to wrap content then it'll automatically adjust to change in text size.

Comment: See the edit I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap_content property to both RelativeLayout and Button like above code ,

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/text_toolbar"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/k_i_n_e_c_t"
                android:padding="2sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Had to change the width to `wrap_content` though

Answer (score 1):

Just take the height from the button with:

```
button.getHeight();
```

set your text size with:

```
button.setTextSize();
```

Comment: That won't work cos they have different dimensions. Besides, I need an xml fix, not Java

Answer (score 1):

If you use this wrap_content the text does't overflow

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Image"
            android:id="@+id/buttonUpload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have used dp as the unit for your textsize. It is preferable to use sp for text dimensions.

[Why should we use sp for font sizes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107920/why-should-we-use-sp-for-font-sizes-in-android)

Comment: That is what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve this by setting width, height & wrap_content of the button.

**Or** you can try by fixing the size of the button and change the button size dynamically as per the text size.